# Use of ffprobe in kivy 'File not Found'

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, kivy, ffprobe, pydub

i am trying to convert audio from webm to mp3 using pudub module in android using kivy. I've included pydub,ffprobe-python,ffmpeg-python in buildozer.spec file but when i run the app i get the following error !

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffprobe'
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to embed ffmpeg suite binaries. ffprobe-python and ffmpeg-python are only connectors to call the binaries.

Comment: how to do this please help !